# I need to list keys in a dictionary that have the same value by user input

Tags: dictionary, input

My task is to ask a user for an input (an instrument) and receive a list of all the musicians that play that instrument. Here is my code:

```
q = input("What instrument do you need: ")

musician_lib = { "Nick Beggs": "Bass", 
                 "Geddy Lee": "Bass", 
                 "John Myung": "Bass",
                 "Steven Wilson": "Guitar",
                 "Neil Peart": "Drums", 
                 "John Petrucci": "Guitar",
                 "Mike Portnoy": "Drums",
                 "Kevin Moore": "Keyboards",
                 "Derek Sherinian": "Keyboards", 
                 "Jordan Rudess": "Keyboards",
                 "Neal Schon": "Guitar",
                 "Steve Perry": "Vox",
                 "Alex Lifeson": "Guitar",
                 "James Labrie": "Vox"
                 }
if q == musician_lib.value:
    print("You should call " + (musician_lib()))
```

I have tried various iterations of calling value or key but I'm getting an error:
*AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'*

To be clear, I would like to see an output similar to this:

What instrument do you need: (user input) Bass

You should call: 
Nick Beggs
Geddy Lee
John Myung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries in python indeed do not have a value attribute which is why you're getting the AttributeError, they do however [have a values() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) that will give you a list of the values in the dict.   Dictionaries also support key() and items() methods which return the keys in the dictionary and the key, value pairs in the dictionary respectively.

From there I would recommend looking into [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get the  keys that match the value the user specified value.

```
musicians = [key for key, value in musician_lib.items() if value == q]
```